# Vue Element Table: undefined nested value crashes Chrome

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using a Vue Element table to display a list of objects that has an object nested in it.

```
"main_list":{
  "id": "1",
  "user": {
    "username": "Bob"
  }
}
```

I can display the username using:

```
<el-table-column prop="user.username" label="User" sortable />
```

Every now and then this page will throw an error stating that it can not read value username of undefined. This will crash Google Chrome to the extent that you have to kill all Chrome processes in the task manager. Firefox does not crash this bad. I think it goes into an infinite loop

I get the data via API, so it might be that some of the user object does not have any usernames.

So far the the only solution that I have found (I'm not sure it is a solution) is:

```
<el-table-column prop="username" label="User">
  <template
    v-if="typeof scope.row.assigned_to !== 'undefined'"
    slot-scope="scope"
  >{{ scope.row.assigned_to.username }}</template>
</el-table-column>
```

Do you have any Idea why this crash happens?
Is there a better solution than mine?

Comment: i think you should do `prop="main_list.user.username"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fetch the list of items, you should update each one of them so that every user has a defined username - even if it is an empty string. Something like

```
axios.get(url).then(result => 
  this.items = result.data.map(item => 
  {
    if(!item.user) item.user = {};
    if(!item.user.username) item.user.username = '';
    return item;
  });
```

You can also try something else:

```
    <el-table-column label="User" sortable :sort-method="sortUsers">
      <template slot-scope="tbl">
        {{ (tbl.row.user || {}).username || 'UNKNOWN' }}
      </template>
    </el-table-column> 

    methods:
    {
      sortUsers(a, b)
      {
        const left = (a.user || {}).username || 'UNKNOWN';
        const right = (b.user || {}).username || 'UNKNOWN';
        if (left < right) return -1;
        if (left > right) return 1;
        return 0;
      }
    }
```